# What is "enlightening" in the sentence?

Tags: grammar, parts-of-speech

"Education is enlightening". What is "enlightening" in the sentence, gerund or participle? I think it's participle, because it's the second verb in the sentence which is continuous form.

Comment: I think it could be either, depending on how you choose to parse/interpret the text. The two possible models being *Education is [the same thing as] enlightenment* (where enlightening = gerund), or *The effect of education is to enlighten* (where it's a participle).

Comment: Most likely it's just an adjective, being used here as a predicate adjective, instead of an attributive adjective, like _That was a very enlightening experience._ Many adjectives were formed from various verb parts, but no longer have verbal superpowers; hence they're neither gerund nor participle, viz, _shelled_ in _soft-shelled crab_ or _writing_ in _writing class_.

Comment: It's advantageously compared with 'interesting' in 'Chemistry is interesting.' Or 'useful' in 'Maths is useful.' As John Lawler says, a deverbal ing-form (neither verbal nor nounal). An adjective.

Answer (score 1):

Enlightening could be either a gerund or a participle, depending on the context. If used as an adjective, it is a participle; if used as a noun, it is a gerund, as my English teacher has taught. In the sentence, "Education is enlightening," the word "enlightening" is functioning as a predicate nominative, renaming education. In this instance, "enlightening" is a gerund.

Comment: Welcome to ELU.SE. Hope, while your answer is fitting, this site strives to provide objective answers. As it stands your answer is purely subjective and could be improved by adding [references](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/59/77227). Take the [tour] or have a look at the [help] to find out more about good answers.

Comment: But your references should focus on participial adjectives rather than participles or gerunds (or any other ing-forms along the verb-noun continuum).